# How to abstract this concept in Objective-c / Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Imagine this handy method called "cycle":

```
str = [str cycle:@[@"blue",@"white",@"red"]];
```

So, the string will cycle through each item of the array, looping around. (If str is not contained in the array, return the same value, let's say.)

Now of course, you could also write such a routine for **integers**, say, which would be very handy.

```
cyl = [cyl cycle:@[@(2),@(4),@(6),@(8),@(12)];
```

and so on.

Another example, it would be handy for enums, something like this:

```
self.picker.cameraFlashMode=
[self.picker.cameraFlashMode // you can't really do that  :)
cycle: @[
        UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn,
        UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff,
        UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto] ];
```

## How to write a method / function / routine for this so it works for all types?

In other words, it should be possible to do something like this,

## x = [x cycle:array];

or maybe some sort of **macro** like this ...

## cycle( x, ..items.. );

no matter what x is.  How would you do that?

Comment: Just do what you're doing with `NSString` and `isEqualToString` except with `NSObject` and `isEqual`?

Comment: the whole method can be replaced with one line `loop[([loop indexOfObject:str]+1)%loop.count]` and it works for any type

Comment: @JoeBlow you need to add `@` before the name so I can see your reply. it is up to your to decide it should throw exception or return first element in array. for category, google it. for primitive type, wrap it using `@(val)` syntax

Comment: I don't think I misunderstood.  `NSObject` is a common ancestor for almost every class in Cocoa.  You could put your category on `NSObject` and use the common `isEqual` comparison.  Do you want to make an array out of primitives, `@[1, 2, 3]`?  You can't do that.  You need to use `NSNumbers` like `@[@(1), @(2), @(3)]`.  And `NSNumber` inherits from `NSObject` so the one category would still do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an NSObject **category** and implement that function. It would only work with objects inheriting from NSObject.

```
@implementation NSObject (myCategory)
- (id)cycle:(NSArray *)array
{
     // code here
}
@end
```

This would not work for other types, but you could use C++ Templates to create a function that works for any data type.

```
template <class type> ret-type cycle(parameter list)
{
   // body of function
}
```

Comment: Merlevede - your C++ solution is beyond me (I"m a humble ObjC programmer). But that looks like exactly it. Is there a chance you could expand on that, i.e. how it would be used?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to read a little about categories. XCode can help you creating the category, by selecting 'new Category' from the file menu, your files will be named NSObject+categoryName.h and .m. Next you `#import` the file wherever you want to use it, and just use `[obj cycle:Array];`.

Comment: Hi Merle .. sorry, you may misunderstand me.  I absolutely completely understand categories, thank goodness :-)  It's a great idea to use "isEqual:" in a NSObject category, I just didn't think of it.. However, I completely fail to understand your second example (the C++) .. your solution for (I guess) primitive types ! Thanks again!

Comment: C++ templates is a huuuuge subject. I would need to copy-paste a whole chapter of a C++ book, and it probably wouldn't be worth the effort. If you're still feeling like your inner-geek is screaming at you, google 'c++ templates' to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an antipattern to me. Consider your example:

```
[str cycle:@[@"blue",@"white",@"red"]];
```

`str` is probably defined as an `NSString`, right? I would consider it a really bad idea for any method on `NSString` to modify the string *in place*, given that it’s an immutable class. You’d probably have to define a category on `NSObject` to get this kind of all-class behavior, but then what about this example?

```
[self.picker.cameraFlashMode cycle:@[
    UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn,
    UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff,
    UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto]];
```

Is `cameraFlashMode` even an object? Remember, you can’t pass messages to instances of an enum type!

**Edited to add…**

If you write something like

```
int a = 1;
```

then a construction like

```
[a cycle:@[@1, @2, @3]];
```

is never going to be valid Objective-C syntax.

Comment: bdsham, you're absolutely correct.  it was just psueodcode (my fault).  I certainly meant it would RETURN the next cyclical value.  I'll edit the question (yet again) immediately  :)  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might be a good opportunity for an `NSEnumerator` subclass.

You'd need to implement `- (id)nextObject` and `- (NSArray*)allObjects`. The only problem I would see is that an `NSEnumerator` typically has an exhaustible list of objects, while this would theoretically continue forever.